# How to remove the last empty keys in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"a               "
```

As you can see there is only one character that is not empty " ". How do I remove the last charaters of the string so only the valid one(s) will remain:

```
"a"
```

This can also be considered in cases where the first characters are empty:

```
"         a"
```

I cannot simply remove each empty key as they can be part of a more complex sentence like this:

```
"I love Js            "
```

Comment: Use the `trim()` method to remove surrounding whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to remove easily the trailing spaces
I suggest that you use the `trim()` method.

`a     '.trim() // return 'a'`